# web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), "ether") shows 55 in red

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

so maybe i'm not understanding, i've left my miner up and running for quiet sometime, and i run a 
`web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), "ether")` on my only single account and it shows up a red 55..

I check that account on etherscanner.io and it shows 0.

so since i was running geth in console mode, i tried sending a transaction, and it indicated exceeded gas limit.

Does this mean i have 55 coins or is this just a bug or something?
Closed Geth to restart miner, and now 
`web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), "ether")` shows 0??

Comment: Ok so i read this thread here. 

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26121/how-to-rescue-my-ether?rq=1

and it was indicating about forcing forked due to unsynced, so i though alright maybe that's my issue. So i restarted my geth, ran eth.syncing until it ran "False". Which i checked indicates is no longer syncing.

Let it run until i got my first job. checked my eth.getBalance, and now i have 5 in red again... yet i cant send again, so i'm sure it's doing the same thing over?

Comment: So i just ran eth.syncing to see what the hell, looks like it restarted my sync since i got the 5.

Comment: Bump to see if i can get an answer... I did a geth removedb, to complete start from scratch. and yet i can reproduce this almost everytime. I'm waiting until eth.syncing shows false. I'm assuming this means i'm synced?

Comment: `red` is the color javascript uses for number type object, it uses `green` for strings, and so on... I don't pay attention to colors, but this has nothing to do with the balance sign.

Comment: What does `eth.blockNumber` returns? If it returns 0 the node is not synced. You can't solo mine until the node synced, otherwise the effort is wasted because the main chain is already pass that point.