# I think I have to edit the gaslimit on geth genesis file, how do I do it?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am getting an error for exceeding gas limit.

I checked current block gas limit by running - eth.getBlock("latest"). It is set to 5000.

I want to increase this, but I have no idea how to.  I have checked this old thread: [Can't send transaction -- "Exceeds block gas limit" or "Intrinsic gas too low"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/cant-send-transaction-exceeds-block-gas-limit-or-intrinsic-gas-too-low)

It says I should edit the genesis file, but how?

Comment: Hi there. Just to check, are you talking about your own private network, or do you want to do this to solve a problem you're hitting on one of the public networks?

Comment: Public Network I think.  Basically I am trying to to run a automated script that will send a tx every 10 minutes.  All my previous interaction with Ethereum is with a GUI.  So I have no idea what I am doing with geth or command line.  I downloaded geth for windows 64 and ran it.  Then I used command line to send a tx.  But it gave me a error for exceeding gas limit.  I found a thread that said I had to check my gaslimit by  running - eth.getBlock("latest").  I did that and it said 5000.  I think I need to change that.   But no idea if editing the genesis file is correct or how to.

Comment: Okay, if it's a public network, then there's no way you can change any of the Genesis values (and this isn't necessarily the best thing to do in a testnet anyway). Do you, or someone you're working with, own the network you're testing on? How have you accessed the network so far? Through which GUI?

Comment: I think my knowledge deficit is too great for what I am trying to do.  I am just using geth.exe and I typed "attached geth" in command line.  I put a wallet file in the keystore folder and I want to send a real transaction through but I get that limit error.  Is there another piece of software that I need in order for me to send a tx?  I was under the impression that I could do everything from just geth and command line.  Sorry I have no dev experience.  I do not know anything about networks, all i am trying to do is send a tx using geth.

Comment: I found out that I have to sync with the network and that was my problem.

Comment: how did you sync to the network, whats the command you use ?

Answer (score 1):

On `geth` the default gas is actually 90000
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/ethapi/api.go#L47

For geth `genesis.json` this is set via the `gasLimit` option, so you can set it to the maximum: `"gasLimit": "0x47e7c4"`

Additionally you'll need to make sure you're sending enough gas with your transaction itself.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I actually do not know how to set the gaslimit option.  What do I type into command line to set the "gaslimit':0x47e7c4"  Apologies I am a complete newb

Comment: It's a `genesis.json` option, so you need to add it there. If you don't know how to, share your genesis.json here.