# Ropsten "exceeds block gas limit"

Tags: gas, ropsten, gas-limit, blocks, failed-transaction

I am on GETH, 1.9.23 and I have had a smart contract running for more than 3 months now.

Suddenly, all transaction failed with "exceeds block gas limit".

I checked the Ropsten Testnet and there is no maintenance going on.

May I know what else do I need to check? I am a bit lost.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/cant-send-transaction-exceeds-block-gas-limit-or-intrinsic-gas-too-low you look here? Is your smart contract funded with ETH? 

Ropsten is also having issues right now, so it might be that.

Comment: Patrick, I am not sure what you mean by funded with ETH. My smart contract does holding some ETH. But today the Block Gas limit had increased to 100,000 which is barely enough for my transaction to go through 90% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Ropsten miners have dropped the block gas limit down to ~40k over the last few days.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/blocks

You will need to use a different testnet until the block gas limit rises again.

Comment: Different address? You mean different testnet?

Comment: Yes! I updated the answer. Thank you.